# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /home/bottl632/public_html/forums/cache/ctpl_admin_overall_header.html.php on line 216
```

It all happened when I installed Automod, then I attempted to install mchat for my phpBB forum. This is my line 16,

```
<?php 
    $this->_tpldata['DEFINE']['.']['LI_USED'] = 1; }} }} } }} 
    if (! $this->_tpldata['DEFINE']['.']['LI_USED']) {  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never trusted AutoMod, you are better off editing the files manually then you know for sure that the edits have been carried out correctly.

Re-upload your backed up copy of the file giving the errors and look through the mChat install instructions to make the changes yourself.